# TFS custom build process activity assemblies per branch

Tags: tfs

What do I do if I want one TFS 2012 build controller to have access to two versions of the same custom build process assembly (one for each of my branches)?

I have one build process template per branch, and one build definition per branch.  Each branch has it's own custom build process assembly, but they all have the same assembly name and namespace (e.g. Company.Build.Activities.dll).  (I realize I could make all of this go away by having different names for each branch's assembly, e.g. Company.Build.Activities.Dev.dll and Company.Build.Activities.Com.dll)

My build controller points to one location for "Version control path to custom assemblies" ($/Build/ForTFS).  I tried putting the two assemblies under different subfolders, but the build process causes an error:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Company\Dev_BuildDef: 

Exception Message: Cannot set unknown member 'Company.Build.Activities.LastActivity.CustomFolderPath'. (type XamlObjectWriterException)
```

It seems that it's using the wrong copy of the assembly (CustomFolderPath is only defined in one assembly, not the other).

I think I could resolve this if I could specify the path or required assembly version in the template xaml, but I am not sure I can do that.  I have read posts that suggest that you can add a reference to the specific assembly version in the Visual Studio project you are using to edit the template.  But that didn't seem to work for me, and how would the build process definition know about that project's references... it only points to the template file itself, not the project.

Any suggestions?  Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Why do you need different assemblies per branch. Your build xaml should be the same between branches, thus the same version of your custom assembly. Any differences should be in your definitions...

Comment: Occasionally the requirements of the build process (for only the development branch) change after the branch has been created.  In this case, we want something different to happen in the development branch, as compared to the commercial branch.

Comment: That does not make sense. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have different assemblies loaded between different branches. You would need to run different controllers and use separate folders.